# in python, self. variable got passed to 2 different variables, are they changing at the same time?

Tags: python

```py
    class LinkList:
        def __init__(self):
            self.head=None   
        def initList(self, data):
            self.head = ListNode(data[0])
            r = self.head
            p = self.head
            for i in data[1:]:
                node = ListNode(i)
                p.next = node
                p = p.next
            return r
```

In the function, `self.head` gets set twice to two different variables - `r` and `p`.

In the for loop only `p` got updated in the loop, what is the difference between `r` and `p` and why `self.head` is passed two times to them?
Do they get updated at the same time?

In other words, `r = self.head` was executed at the very beginning of the program, the value should not changed anymore, but seems like after the whole function got executed, `r` automatically updated, is it because `self.head` makes it updated?  and how `self.head` got updated itself?

Comment: `self.head`, `p` and `r` will all be references to the same object initially. `p` is replaced in the loop later if `data` is long enough.

Comment: The function returns r because the function is defined to return r. What do you want it to return?

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger and you'll be able to see what happens for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`p` is used as a sliding pointer, visiting each node in the list once. `r` is used to remember where the first node was and the first node (the start of the list) is returned with `return r`. However, the line `r = self.head` is superfluous, instead the function could just end with `return self.head`

Comment: thanks a lot! I wonder since r = self.head was executed at the very beginning of the program, the value should not changed anymore, but seems like after the for loop got executed, r automatically updated, is it because self.head makes it updated? and how self.head got updated itself?  thanks so much! I have been studying python for a couple months, but still got confused with the usage of "self "

Comment: `self` is just the name of the first parameter of a method of an object, and a method is just a function that's defined as part of a class. Every time an method gets called, the object it is called for is passed as the value of that first parameter `self`. So, `self.head` means `<this object's value of>.head`. In this code, `self.head` is set to a new `ListNode` object, then `p` is pointed at the same object, and `p.next` is updated, which of course also modifies `self.head.next` - it's the same thing.